# A flexbox layout with an item pinned to each side of the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm looking to create a layout like the snippets below using flexbox and maintaining a flat hierarchy - meaning that all four panes are siblings.

My first solution uses absolute positioning, which isn't flexbox and doesn't provide good synergy between the panes (overlapping, "underlapping", etc).

My second solution uses flexbox, but uses 3 rows with the left and right panes both in the middle row, and the top and bottom panes in their own rows, so the hierarchy is a little messy.

Is there a way to do this? If not, how should I best mitigate the messy hierarchy of the second solution?

**Solution #1** (absolute position, panes don't mesh well):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.tray {
  /* display: flex; */
  /* justify-content: center; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top {
  top: 0%;
  height: 20%;
  width: 60%;
}

.tray-bottom {
  bottom: 0%;
  height: 20%;
  width: 60%;
}

.tray-left {
  left: 0%;
  height: 60%;
  width: 10%;
}

.tray-right {
  right: 0%;
  height: 60%;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="tray tray-top">top</div>
  <div class="tray tray-left">left</div>
  <div class="tray tray-right">right</div>
  <div class="tray tray-bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

**Solution #2** (flexbox with nested hierarchy):

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: tan;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.row-top {
  flex-basis: 40px;
}

.row-middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-bottom {
  flex-basis: 40px;
}

.pane {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
  flex-basis: 40px;
}

.pane-top {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}

.pane-bottom {
  flex-basis: 60%;
}

.pane-left {
  /* align-self: flex-start; */
}

.pane-right {
  /* align-self: flex-end; */
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="row row-top">
    <div class="pane pane-top">top</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-middle">
    <div class="pane pane-left">left</div>
    <div class="pane pane-right">right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-bottom">
    <div class="pane pane-bottom">bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just change the direction to row and add wrapping:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}

.tray-bottom {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
}

.tray-left {
  height: 60%;
  width: 10%;
}

.tray-right {
  height: 60%;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="tray tray-top">top</div>
  <div class="tray tray-left">left</div>
  <div class="tray tray-right">right</div>
  <div class="tray tray-bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

As per comment - pad out remaining width with margin:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#root {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

.tray {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.tray-top {
  height: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 20%;
}

.tray-bottom {
  height: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 25%;
}

.tray-left {
  height: 60%;
  width: 10%;
}

.tray-right {
  height: 60%;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="tray tray-top">top</div>
  <div class="tray tray-left">left</div>
  <div class="tray tray-right">right</div>
  <div class="tray tray-bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I should've used less misleading constants. I want those four panes to be attached to their respective screen edges regardless of size. With wrapping, if the top and bottom panes aren't 100% width (a case I want to support), then this doesn't work. I'll update my question with a better example.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this? If not, how should I best mitigate the messy hierarchy of the second solution?

Absolute positioning is not an ideal solution because, as you noted, it removes the panes from the document flow.

Flexbox is not great either because, as you also noted, it adds layers to the HTML structure.

A clean and simple solution can be had with CSS Grid Layout:

```css
#root {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(100, 1vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(100, 1vh);
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.pane-top    { grid-column: 25 / 75 ; grid-row:  1 /  10; }
.pane-bottom { grid-column: 25 / 75 ; grid-row: -1 / -10; }

.pane-left   { grid-column:  1 /  10; grid-row: 25 / 75;  }
.pane-right  { grid-column: -1 / -10; grid-row: 25 / 75;  }


/* non-essential demo styles */
.pane {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;  
  border: thin solid black;
}

body { margin: 0;}
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <div class="pane pane-top">top</div>
    <div class="pane pane-left">left</div>
    <div class="pane pane-right">right</div>
    <div class="pane pane-bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zo15Lr6h/)